# Performance of a get unique elements/group by operation on an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable

I was wondering how could I improve the performance of the following code:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

//In my case I have 30000
IEnumerable<MyObject> data = MethodThatReturnsManyMyObjects(); 

var groupedByYear = data.GroupBy(x => x.Year); 

//Here is the where it takes around 5 seconds
foreach (var group in groupedByYear) 
    //do something here.
```

The idea is to get a set of objects with unique year values. In my scenario there are only 6 years included in the 30000 items in the list so the foreach loop will be executed 6 times only. So we have many items needing to be grouped in a few groups.

Using the .Distinct() with an explicit IEqualityComparer would be an alternative but somehow I feel that it wont make any difference.

I can understand if 30000 items is too much and that i should be happy with the 5 seconds I get, but I was wondering if the above can be imporved performance wise.

Thanks.

EDIT:
The answers below made me dig a bit deeper only to realize that the 5 seconds I am getting only heppens when the data are loaded into memory from the DB. The delay was disguised inside the foreach loop as the deferred execution of the IEnumerable delayed it until that point confusing me to assume that probably the GroupBy() could be refactored to something more performant.

The question still stands though, is the GroupBy() command the optimal way to achieve the best performance in such cases?

Comment: Just curious, where is MethodThatReturnsManyMyObjects getting the objects from?

Comment: Do you need only the 6 unique year values, or do you need the MyObject objects corresponding to each of those 6 years?

Comment: @Ian P: The data are all in memory. They are get either from the db and kept in memory berfore are provided to the IEnumerable or are comming from a cached in memory object.

Comment: @Lasse: I need the 6 MyObject instances that include the unique years.

Comment: Hmm.. If you were using a lazy ORM to retrive the data, then it would make sense for the GroupBy operation to take a bit longer due to the fact that the retrieval is happening at the time it is actually used. Not sure, but in my example, it runs in less than a second with 350,000 records and a similar object structure to what you outlined. Good luck!

Comment: @IanP: Spot on! The delay is due to the DB loading the data into memory. It was disguised in the foreach loop as the IEnumerable deffered the execution of loading the data in memory util that point.

Comment: @tolism7, that makes no sense. If there are 10000 objects that have the same year, which of them do you want? (and don't say "I don't care" because the database cares, the code cares)

Comment: @Lasse: I am sorry because I indeed do not care as all 10000 objects in my collection that have the same year carry the same attribute that I want to get. That is why I do not care. Initially I did not want to do a group by at the DB (bad idea.. i know) so that is why I loaded the data into the memory in an IEnumerable (IList) and I was doing the groupby there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definitely shouldn't take that long. Is this running under the debugger, or not? Are any exceptions being thrown? Does the Year property perform any calculations in real life? It should execute this almost instantly, to be honest.

Do you have a short but complete program which demonstrates it taking a long time? (If not, I'll try to come up with one myself to get some sample timings.)

Note that if `MethodThatReturnsManyMyObjects` is using deferred execution for the iterator, that could be the culprit - how long does it take if you call `data.ToList()` for example?

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the insight. I am currently trying to get better benchamrk times to provide. I'll have something to show in a bit.

Comment: I suspect that deferred evaluation is the issue. In a simple example I made based on the criteria provided, it is almost instant with 350,000 samples.

Comment: @Ian & Jon: I have just veryfied the perfomance my self. The method that fetches the data can get them from the database OR an in memory cache. Whenever the in-memory cache provides data the process takes 20 milliseconds but when the data come from the DB (using NHibernate) and even thought I make sure they are loaded in memory first and that the DB is not hit more than once I do get 6 seconds. I need to dig deeper to find out why.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to know: does your `MethodThatReturnsManyMyObjects` provide lazy evaluation (i.e., using the `yield` keyword)? If so, **that** could be your culprit, rather than the call to `GroupBy`:

```
// if MethodThatReturnsManyMyObjects uses yield, then
// it won't be executed until enumeration
IEnumerable<MyObject> data = MethodThatReturnsManyMyObjects();

// still not executed
var groupedByYear = data.GroupBy(x => x.Year); 

// finally executed here
foreach (var group in groupedByYear)
    // ...
```